# Most Powerful Being On Earth

Tags: biology, super-powers, energy, metabolism, power-scaling

Okay, with my power system, I want to have these ranks:

- F Rank: Average power level of species
- C Rank: Most powerful member of species
- B Rank: Most powerful living being native to a planet
- A Rank: Most powerful being native to a galaxy
- S Rank: Most powerful being in the universe

For example, if a being is C Rank, then they are not counted as F Rank, to be frank. And I don't have a rank for "most powerful being native to a solar system", as solar systems tend to have only a handful of life-bearing bodies, while galaxies have thousands, if not millions. Let's say that we have Earth, and with all living beings on it, and there is this one human who is B Rank. To be simple, we will calculate power level in energy used in a day per body mass (Calories/(Time*Mass)), and all species known to science are viable contenders. If we have a 70-kg human, how much metabolic energy will they need to use in a day to be considered the most powerful being on the planet?

Comment: I think your question can be simplified in: what is the highest metabolic rate per unit mass among all creatures living on Earth?

Comment: This isn't a problem that needs to be solved or even about world building. You just want people to do your research for you. In order to avoid that impression, where exactly did you get stuck? You do even have a mathematical expression in there which tells me that you spend more time on you're question than most. That's why it's so disappointing that you're just trying to outsource your research

Comment: My mom is A rank cause she squash the Galaxy (S10) easily with only her bum and babies should be categorized as S rank as they likes peek-a-boo!

Comment: Oh one more thing, if you make a human eat and burn as much as you require, they will die, from metabolic issues, poisoning or simply from heat. So you've got two options: magic or cybernetics. My advice to you: ask yourself what you want to do with those calories first l, someone might come up with a solution that might actually get what you want. This seems to be a random ranking without purpose atm

Comment: Well, a more powerful being would be using more energy, so that's what I'm basing my estimates on.

Comment: Have you tried to do the math?

Comment: I strongly suggest that if this scale gets out to the public, if would be modified A-E, because people like easy comparisons.

Comment: @TysonDennis When "that's what I'm basing my estimates on" which estimates are those?

In any case, how does the metabolic energy a 70-kg human use in a day to be considered the most powerful being on the planet change the ranking of your B-class relative to F, C, A or S??

Comment: S stands for supreme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to World Atlas, the highest average metabolic rate on Earth belongs to ruby-throated hummingbirds, who can require up to 7.6 calories per day.

https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/which-animal-has-the-fastest-metabolism.html

The ruby-throated hummingbird, according to Wikipedia, weighs between 2 and 6 grams. We’ll use 2 grams.

Using your own equation: 7.6 calories  / (0.002 kilograms x 1 day) = 3,800 cal/(kg-day).

A 70 kilogram human, then, would need to burn 266,000 calories per day to achieve this same metabolic burn.

Comment: Besides the added calculation, how is this different from Demigan his answer?

Comment: You've included the mistake your source made. Top athletes eat up to or more than 10 million calories a day.

Comment: @trioxidane - just the final calculation, and pulling up both the mass of the hummingbird, it’s calorie consumption, and providing references

Comment: @raditz_35 Which top atheles eat tens of millions calories? According to this source, with some specific athletes listed, it’s a few thousand- https://coach.nine.com.au/fitness/crazy-high-calorie-diets-of-athletes/77cbeeca-175e-4274-84f0-1277e1233531

Comment: Ok, let's just spell it out. It's kcal, not cal. Some pros eat more than 10.000 kcal a day. I see that a lot websites make this mistake. Apparently it's common place in the us to say cal but mean kcal. It's still just wrong and makes you look like you have no idea

Comment: @Raditz_35 then edit the post.

Comment: A lot can be done with that energy, that's for sure. It's literally 1.11 GJ per day.

Comment: If you only added the calculation, why not ask to add it to Demigan his answer? It's a minor addition to the answer.

Comment: @trioxidane , it might seem like a small change to you (looking at it a second time, I can see your point-of-view). However, I’m not certain that my answer doesn’t change the meaning of the other answer. The first time I read the other answer, I took it to be general notes about body mass and volume, otherwise I would have not answered at all and merely upvoted. I’ve rarely edited other people’s content for more than grammar / math. Happy to ask for permission, if you feel that’s important.

Comment: @Raditz_35 “calories” is commonly used across all English speaking countries (not just the US) to mean kcal. It’s not scientific, but it’s also not wrong, and your objections feel very pedantic.

Comment: I heard a rumor circa 2001 of a bacterium that was found that powered itself with uranium by fission process. If true, ...

Comment: @tim this is an international site. It's certainly not used this way in my country. Just a minor edit to avoid big mistakes

Comment: @Raditz_35 I don’t know what country you’re in, so I couldn’t comment, but it’s the second definition here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+calorie, so it’s certainly not US only. Wikipedia even redirects kcal to calorie! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie.

Comment: @tim according to EU law, only kcal and not cal is allowed on all product descriptions . I get that it's common in the us, I do. But please consider, I've a degree in chemistry, a lot of experience with calorie counting and I've never seen it before as used in the English speaking world. If I've never seen that, there are many people from outside the us, uk or whatever that have never encountered that. I can't speak for the rest of the world, but it's such a minor and strictly correct change. Why argue about it even?

Comment: @Raditz_35 again, I wasn’t claiming it was used in product descriptions. I said it was commonly used. Having a degree in chemistry has nothing to do with how words are commonly used I’m afraid! If you go around saying “I eat 10 million calories” people will be *more* confused than saying “I eat 2000 calories”, not less! Again: you might not have seen it before, but it’s the title of the Wikipedia page, and it’s a definition in the dictionary! Consider you could be being pedantic here!

Answer (score 7):

Your most powerful being is going to be small because of the criteria.

Small creatures have relatively more surface area compared to the volume of their body, this makes them lose heat much faster than larger creatures. To compensate their metabolic rate (more specifically their mitochondria) is much higher to keep warm. Consequently they need to eat more to stay alive.

The Hummingbird would currently be our B-rank, it needs to eat its body weight in nectar in a day. So your human would need to be eating more than 70kg of food a day. Perhaps there are bacteria that could be considered more powerful but I'm not sure.

Comment: To an inexperienced world builder, it could be beneficial to point out that it's not just necessity but also availability. Small creatures can afford to eat that much because there is enough food. A blue whale can't get bigger because there is not enough food in the ocean, they're already eating continuously. May seem obvious, but from what I've seen here over the years,it's not. Smallness is not the reason for high metabolism, but what allows it